# Library like pyparsing for PHP

Tags: php, parsing

I would like to know: is there something like [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) (a recursive descent parser) for PHP?
I already looked for it, but it seems no one did it yet. I hope I am wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Custom nested expressions with different enclosing characters. Not a simple thing with Regex :-(

Comment: @stereofrog: that project seems to be dead, but I'll have a look. Thank you.

Comment: @Alberteddu: Could you give an example / a formal grammar? Depending on what exactly it is, it might be better to use a recursive regex (you can do recursion in regex and it's easy) or a hand written regex lexer and parser or a parser generator. Depends on the complexity of the grammar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know any maintained parser generators written in PHP. But there are parser generators written in other languages with PHP as a target language. One I have personally used is kmyacc. There is a [PHP and Windows compatible fork](https://github.com/moriyoshi/kmyacc-forked) of it. The grammar for it is written in yacc format and can be compiled to PHP using this command:

```
kmyacc -l -m %PARSER_PROTOTYPE_FILE% -p %NAME% %GRAMMAR_FILE%
```

Kmyacc already comes with a procedural parser prototype file for PHP, but I personally use [a modified version](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser/blob/master/grammar/kmyacc.php.parser) of an [OOP based prototype](https://bitbucket.org/moriyoshi/phython/src/28afbd3a66ed/kmyacc.class.php.parser).

As an example: [This grammar](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser/blob/master/grammar/zend_language_parser.phpy) get's compiled into [this parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser/blob/master/lib/PHPParser/Parser.php). (Note that the grammar is huge, that's why the generated parser has two and a half thousand lines. A "normal" grammar would obviously be far smaller.)

Comment: Thi is very interesting. I'm going to take a look. Thanks a lot (obviously if that's what I need I'll check as answered).

Answer (score 2):

If all you need to parse are "custom expressions", you can probably code a recursive descent parser by hand fairly easily, if you have already written down your grammar.

See this SO answer for details: [Is there an alternative for flex/bison that is usable on 8-bit embedded systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245962/is-there-an-alternative-for-flex-bison-that-is-usable-on-8-bit-embedded-systems/2336769#2336769)

Comment: Hehe, always bumping into you on parsing questions :)

Comment: @NikiC: Bad side effect of doing that for a living for 40 years :-}

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/message/view/home/41772107

Comment: Thank you. I did find this but it's not what I need. I'll have to parse complex strings

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing